# How to migrate SQL Server database from my server to client server

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas

I have a `Transaction` database with 10,000+ entries inserted on daily basis.

My client's requirement is that we allow him to download reports from his own server, for this we make a same copy of `Transaction` database to his server.

But now problem is how do we move data at a specific time to his server which takes latest data entry?

Comment: 10 entries a day?In ten years that still under 40,000 records. Just take a compressed backup and send it and restore it. There are also report-only options, cubes and cloud options to consider.

Comment: Sorry it is 10k+ per day and i want a automatic process

Comment: A backup / transfer / restore can be automated. Two other options for synchronising databases are replication and CDC. To do something at a certain time I suggest you use SQL Agent. Come back with some more specific questions.

Comment: You've tagged SSAS, the SQL Server cubing engine. Is this a technology you want to use to solve the problem? maybe you mean SSIS?

Comment: Have you considered and ETL process using SSIS?, with SSIS you can even transfer only the data that you need for reporting.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a couple of options in SQL Server.

If you can connect to your customer's database, Change data capture with SSIS is one option. CDC collects all changes in a queryable store which SSIS then reads and pushes to your target. You can be as selective as you want on what to move over since you write the ETL process in SSIS. One downside to CDC is it's in enterprise edition only. See detailed instructions at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895315(v=sql.105).aspx

Transactional replication is another option which is available in both enterprise and standard editions. This has been around along time and used by a lot of organizations to do exactly what you described - incrementally move data to another database. Not as flexible as CDC but you can still apply filters to what rows/columns get moved. Not needed enterprise edition is helpful for many customers. Lots of detail about the technology here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198(v=sql.105).aspx but highly encourage you to check out Kendra Little's most excellent article that covers trans repl and compares it with CDC http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/09/transactional-replication-change-tracking-data-capture/

If you can't connect directly to the customer database, CDC with SSIS still works but the output target will be some flat file which then gets transferred to the customer and loaded using another SSIS package or some other bulk load job (TSQL, BCP, etc...). Do be careful with how the flat file gets moved since anybody can see its contents.

I'd avoid any manual methods like creating triggers or running some (usually expensive) query to find the changed rows. Apart from the maintenance efforts, you're very likely to encounter tough performance issues.

Comment: if user can also change column in transnational database then which approach is best. ?

Comment: Change column as in alter the schema? Transactional replication does support changes to the published object with some limitations (docs have details). Be careful with dropping columns, they are always replicated. That aside, what do you expect to change and where? Occasional changes to columns, especially adding columns, is expected but if it happens regularly that's not a good thing. CDC is a bit more involved when changing schema, pretty much have to re-establish CDC. SSIS can be made handle changes if you script against metadata instead of hard coded object names.